# c# Convert base64 to jpg image

Tags: c#

```
  protected void ExportToImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string base64 = Request.Form[hfImageData.UniqueID].Split(',')[1];
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
        File.Copy(bytes.ToString()+".jpg", "\\\\192.168.2.9\\Web");
    }
```

hfImageData data i get from jquery,after user do the drawings,i will convert the **convas** into base64 .
then will call c# function to convert from base64 to jpg image file into server and store into DB.

when i trigger the onclick button im getting error :**System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'System.Byte[].jpg'.**

any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line `File.Copy(bytes.ToString()+".jpg", "\\\\192.168.2.9\\Web");` you are effectively trying to convert content of the bytes array and use it as an image name, but this will not actually create the file.

`bytes.ToString()` simply returns the type of the object not the content. That's why you are seeing `System.Byte[].jpg`

The way to solve the issue is to change your function:

```
protected void ExportToImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string base64 = Request.Form[hfImageData.UniqueID].Split(',')[1];
    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
    //write the bytes to file:
    File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\temp\somefile.jpg", bytes); //write to a temp location.
    File.Copy(@"c:\temp\somefile.jpg", @"\\192.168.2.9\Web");//here we grab the file and copy it.
    //EDIT: based on permissions you might be able to write directly to the share instead of a temp folder first.
}
```

Comment: i'm getting this error ,The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrec

Comment: I have updated my answer, maybe try to escape the complete strings using the @ -symbol

Answer (score 3):

`bytes.ToString()` does not return anything meaningful.

Your bytes aren't a file; you can't copy them.

Instead, call `File.WriteAllBytes()` to write them directly to a new file.

Comment: you mean this? File.Copy(File.WriteAllBytes(bytes) + ".jpg", "\\\\192.168.2.5\\Web");